# Pop up messages in excel when entering specific words into a cell

Tags: excel, vba

Working off a macro I found on here, I managed to get a delivery requirement pop-up to work when entering a specific postcode. However, when I try and duplicate this for multiple postcodes with different delivery requirements I get 'Compile error: Block If without End If'.

First macro is the one that works for a single postcode & the second is the one where the error message appears (both have postcodes removed for GDPR).

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:Z99")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target = "xxx xxx" Then
            MsgBox "HI-AB DELIVERY REQUIRED."
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:Z99")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target = "xxx xxx" Then
            MsgBox "HI-AB DELIVERY REQUIRED."
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:Z99")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target = "axx xx" Then
            MsgBox "NO DELIVERIES BEFORE 8AM."
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

I only want the pop up to appear when the specific post code is entered. Is this possible?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: You need to get familiar with the If-Then-Else Statement. You may want to see [If Then Else Statement](https://youtu.be/JmT7Gv4K-d4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get familiar with the `If-Then-Else` Statement.

Your code can be written as

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:Z99")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target = "xxx xxx" Then MsgBox "HI-AB DELIVERY REQUIRED."
        If Target = "axx xx" Then MsgBox "NO DELIVERIES BEFORE 8AM."
    End If
End Sub
```

or better

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:Z99")) Is Nothing Then
        Select Case Target
            Case "xxx xxx": MsgBox "HI-AB DELIVERY REQUIRED."
            Case "axx xx": MsgBox "NO DELIVERIES BEFORE 8AM."
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'll be honest, I'm a rookie at best so I think some studying up is needed!

I've tried the above & it works fine for the first target and message, however, when typing in the second one I don't get a message box

Comment: The code that I gave you above just showed how to write the if then else. I have modified the code to do what you exactly want. you may have to refresh the page to see the changes

Comment: You may want to restrict this to one cell with e.g. `If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub` to avoid a type mismatch error when more than one cell intersects (when copy-pasting multiple cells).

Comment: @VBasic2008: Yes you are right. I have explained about it in [Why MS Excel crashes and closes during Worksheet_Change Sub procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860894/why-ms-excel-crashes-and-closes-during-worksheet-change-sub-procedure/13861640#13861640)

Comment: ...and I upvoted it ages ago when I hardly knew what events are.